# How to include multiple predictors (int and string types) in sk-learn machine learning pipeline?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

Here is the data table:

[image]

I am following this ML [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-label-text-classification-with-scikit-learn-30714b7819c5), and customized the code for my needs as follow, the goal is to use some predictor(s) to predict the label which is a multiclass label. I have also created dummy variables based on the `'label'` column, as in the tutorial.

```
df = pd.read_csv(directory_data+final_data_file, encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)

# Text cleaning
def clean_text(text):
    text = text.lower()
    text = re.sub(r"what's", "what is ", text)
    text = text.strip(' ')
    return text

df['study_title'] = df['study_title'].map(lambda com: clean_text(com))
df['study_desc'] = df['study_desc'].map(lambda com: clean_text(com))
df['condition'] = df['condition'].map(lambda com: clean_text(com))

df['min_age'] = df['min_age'].astype(int)

# Split data into train and test sets
# Need to do a sophisticated randomization since currently same study can occupy multiple columns
# Need to first randomize study ids into train or test sets
# Then remap the studies into the sets based on the matching study ids
unique_study_id_list = cf.unique(df, 'study_id')

rand_seed = 888
random.seed(rand_seed)
random.shuffle(unique_study_id_list)

percent_test = 0.50
test_study_id = unique_study_id_list[0:int(len(unique_study_id_list)*percent_test)]
train_study_id = unique_study_id_list[(int(len(unique_study_id_list)*percent_test)):]

test = df[df['study_id'].isin(test_study_id)]
train = df[df['study_id'].isin(train_study_id)]

# Specify what to traing with
X_train = train['study_desc']
X_test = test['study_desc']

# ML pipeline: define a pipeline combining a text feature extractor with multi lable classifier
NB_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words)),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(MultinomialNB(
        fit_prior=True, class_prior=None))),])

LogReg_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words)),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression(solver='sag'), n_jobs=1)),])

SVC_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words)),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(), n_jobs=1)),])

#######################
#######################
#######################
# Testing outputs
categories = cf.unique(df, 'label')

output_switch = 'test2' # 'real' or 'test' or 'off'

if output_switch == 'test':
    print (df['label'].value_counts())

elif output_switch == 'test2':
    for category in categories:
        print('... Processing {}'.format(category))
        # train the model using X_dtm & y
        NB_pipeline.fit(X_train, train[category])
        # compute the testing accuracy
        prediction = NB_pipeline.predict(X_test)
        print('Test auc-score is {}'.format(roc_auc_score(test[category], prediction)))

else: pass
```

However, I have not figured how to modify the following to include multiple predictors. Currently I am using `'study_desc'` only, but how can I also include `'study_title'` and `'min_age'` as my predictors?

I have tried the following but got errors:

```
X_train = train['study_desc', 'study_title', 'min_age']
X_test = test['study_desc', 'study_title', 'min_age']

KeyError: ('study_desc', 'study_title', 'min_age')
```

And

```
X_train = train[['study_desc', 'study_title', 'min_age']]
X_test = test[['study_desc', 'study_title', 'min_age']]

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3, 3649]
```

////////////////////
Edits: trying out the suggested reference:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion

class ItemSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, data_dict):
        return data_dict[self.key]

NB_pipeline_multi = Pipeline([
    ('union', FeatureUnion(
        transformer_list=[

            ('min_age', Pipeline([
                ('selector', ItemSelector(key='min_age')),
            ])),

            ('study_title', Pipeline([
                ('selector', ItemSelector(key='study_title')),
                ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words)),

            ])),

            ('study_desc', Pipeline([
                ('selector', ItemSelector(key='study_desc')),
                ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words)),
            ])),
        ],
        )),

        ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(MultinomialNB(fit_prior=True, class_prior=None))),
    ])

KeyError: 'min_age'
```

Comment: you might want to check [this question + answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466193/how-to-add-a-feature-to-a-vectorized-data-set)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to combine your tf-idf features with standard numerical/categorical features. You can achieve this by using a `FeatureUnion` transformer. Two very nice resources are here - [API docu](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) and an [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-hetero-feature-union-py). The example is very relevant for your application because it also implements an `ItemSelector` transformer that enables selection of specific columns in a `pd.DataFrame`.

Comment: Make sure you are feeding the original pd.DataFrame to .fit and .predict --- all columns included